# How to change the url with history.pushState to create a page transition with jQuery Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, transition

I am trying to achieve a seamless page transition using window.history.pushState(), to change the url in the address bar. I followed the this [tutorial](https://www.superhi.com/video/simple-page-transitions-with-jquery-and-javascript), but pushState throws the following error: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL [link] cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL`

Does anyone know how to fix this. The thing I trying to achieve is, to get the href of the button that is clicked and change the url for example from: `http://www.example.com/index.html` to `http://www.example.com/about.html`.

```
$('.button').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        window.history.pushState(null, null, href); 

        $.ajax({
            url: href,
            success: function(data) {
                // Do animation and change content
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not get that error message if you were trying to change the URL from `http://www.example.com/index.html`.

A `null` origin is one on a page with a URL starting `file:`.

You need to run the JS in a page with an origin which isn't `null`. i.e. on a web server with an HTTP(S) URL.